# How do I find out what version of upstart I have?

Tags: upstart, versions

I'm trying to figure out if I should use User Jobs or Session Jobs, since Session Jobs are the proper way to do things from upstart 1.7 onward.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

How do I find out what version of upstart is in use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command to find the version is `initctl version`. It should have output along the lines of `init (upstart 1.12)`.

Another method is running `apt-cache policy upstart` and looking at what version it says is installed.

There has never been an `upstart` binary/command shipped in Ubuntu; I have no idea what the other answer is talking about.

Edit: apparently /sbin/upstart is shipped in 14.10 on in the upstart-bin package (presumably for user sessions).

Comment: `which upstart` /sbin/upstart hmm?

Comment: What does `dpkg -S /sbin/upstart` say? That command tells you what package owns the file.

Comment: @Rinzwind It started in 14.10: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=utopic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=upstart, the package is called `upstart-bin`.